# Is the Implementation of boost::vf2_graph_iso Single-threaded?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, graph

I am using the boost graph library for a graph pattern matching project. I used `boost::vf2_graph_iso` for checking isomorphism for subgraphs with the number of vertices up to 10. There are hundereds to thousands of subgraphs and I need to push all of them into a hash set. It takes very long time for the job. An naive idea to boost the performance is to use parallel hash set with multi threads.

I tried multi threads, which indeed reduces the overall running time to a certain extent, but I found that during the execution, the cpu usage shows as only one core is being used. To be detailed, my machine has 32 cores and I create 28 threads but the peak CPU usage is only 100%, instead of 2800%. I also use `boost::vf2_subgraph_mono` and `boost::vf2_subgraph_iso`, which have the same behavior.

I did not use lock in the implementation. Each thread accesses only one partiton of the hash set, i.e., the access is lock-free and does not use any atomic operation.

I guess whether `boost::vf2_graph_iso` is restricted to single-threaded? I.e., although multiple threads can call `boost::vf2_graph_iso` at the same time but somewhere inside gets locked? I don't know how to verify my guess. So I am wondering if anyone has any idea on the above? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. [padding padding padding] (And no, it does not share state so will not block on resources)

Comment: @sehe I think you are saying the impl is single-threaded but `boost::vf2_graph_iso` is not restricted to be single-threaded. Instead, it can be embarrassingly parallel. I agree as the doc does not mention anything about parallelism. But that does not explain the low peak CPU usage. :(

Comment: Saying "boost::vf2_graph_iso is not restricted to be single-threaded. Instead, it can be embarrassingly parallel" sounds confusing. People might think it will tself employ threads. Which it will not. However, on (immutable/non-shared) graphs you may run the algorithm in parallel. Indeed that doesn't explain your problem which is why this was a comment. YOu should show the code that parallellizes things.

Comment: OMG, You are right. You inspired me to write a small prototype to reproduce the problem. I tried but I cannot reproduce. In the prototype, the peak CPU usage reached 2800%. Now I found the problem was that when I create the threads, these threads are somehow attached to the same physical core (with unknown reason). Then I tried to manually assign the threads to different cores and finally fixed the CPU usage problem. Thx!! @sehe